# Internal desktop ODD as external to laptop

Tags: laptop, desktop-computer, blu-ray, esata

I have been looking for a decent blu-ray burner mainly for backup purposes. It seems as though desktop BD burners have much higher write speed compared to the slim-line ones. I was wondering if I can power up and run a internal desktop SATA ODD as external to a laptop using a eSATA to SATA cable? I got this cable specifically to connect a SATA 2.5' HDD to the eSATA port. 
Is the ODD SATA port different from the HDD SATA port? Also will there be enough power from the laptop? The eSATA cable has a y-cable, which has another USB port for power.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between Optical Drive SATA devices and spinning rust SATA.  If you have a working cable from an eSATA port to SAta then you can use this just fine for your burner.

> Also will there be enough power from the laptop?

You really should use an external power supply. eSATA does not provide any power, so you would need that anyway.  There are 'powered eSATA' connectors which provide **limited** power. Usually enough to spin a 2½ inch drive. But desktop CD/DVD writers draw much more.

(I never had a BR writer, so I am assuming those also draw a lot more).

There should be no problem with a case which you can also use to power regular 3½ inch harddrives though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will look for enclosures. As an experiment, would you suggest running a desktop DVD drive off the cable. If this works, would it then also be able to drive a BD burner with the same power?

Comment: Great stuff! Will check it out.

Comment: Hi, got a quick finding that I would like to check out. My laptop has a eSATAp port, I think, (http://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/_processed_/csm_A_rechts_48_7607945722.jpg), which I think is rated for higher power and voltage. Would this work without an enclosure?

Comment: I found this (https://www.amazon.co.uk/DiGiYes%C2%AE-Drive-Converter-Adapter-Supply/dp/B0197MJ01G/ref=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_t), which seems to be a pretty cost effective solution. Do you think that it would work?

Comment: From what I see, I think that the drive supports both +5 and +12v. Here is the products specs (http://images10.newegg.com/UploadFilesForNewegg/itemintelligence/Pioneer/BDR_209DBK_Pro_Spec_Rev1_20011445191870512.pdf). However, the peak maximum quoted power is 2500mA. Would this be a issue with a 2000mA supply?

Comment: This is getting to long for comments. Let me clean up my old one. As to would it work, the product you linked to uses oth +5v and +12v, aswell as more than you linked to. It will overload the PSU. Which litterally might cause a burn,